# Points in unit square

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $n$ points be given in the unit square. How to prove or disprove: the points can be labeled $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to satisfy the inequality $$\|x_1-x_2\|^2 +\|x_2-x_3\|^2+\cdots+\|x_n-x_1\| ^2 \le 4,$$ where $\|\cdot\| $ is [the Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)?

Comment: Just making sure: is the problem stated precisely? I ask because I know of a similar problem, which says: let $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ be points in the unit disk, and let $d_i=\min_k d(x_i,x_k)$. Show that $d_1^2+\ldots d_n^2\leq 16$. If your problem is coming from a competition-math type source, then this would be a more interesting problem to consider.

Comment: No, this is not a problem from a student mathematical olimpiad. You may ask your question separately.

Comment: I know the answer to the question I gave, just making sure your question is precisely stated.

Comment: @proximal : BTW, your question is not similar to this because a cycle should be found. In your question the sum of the minimal squared distances is estimated from above.

Comment: I'm aware it's not the same type of problem. Please just let it go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I've seen this problem before, and I'm guessing in Mathematical Gems by Ross, but I'm not too sure. I'm also lazy with the notation, and am treating them as points, instead of coordinates.]

**Lemma:** Let $ABC$ be a right triangle with $\angle ABC = 90^\circ $. THere are $n$ points in/on the triangle. Then, it is possible to find a sequence of points such that

$$ |Ax_1^2 | + |x_1 x_2|^2 + \ldots + |x_k B|^2 + |Bx_{k+1}|^2 + \ldots + |x_nC|^2 \leq |AC|^2$$

**Proof:** We proceed by induction on the number of points.

Let $BD$ be the perpendicular to side $AC$. Apply the induction hypothesis, to get

$$ |Ax_1^2 | + |x_1 x_2|^2 + \ldots + |x_i D|^2 + |Dx_{i+1}|^2 + \ldots + |x_jB|^2 \leq |AB|^2$$

$$ |Bx_{j+1}^2 | + |x_{j+1} x_{j+2}|^2 + \ldots + |x_k B|^2 + |Bx_{k+1}|^2 + \ldots + |x_nC|^2 \leq |BC|^2$$

Now, it remains to show that $|x_i D|^2 + |Dx_{i+1}|^2 \leq |x_ix_{i+1}|^2$, but this is obvious because $\angle x_i D x_{i+1}$ is at most $90^\circ$. Ditto for $|x_k D|^2 + |Dx_{k+1}|^2 \leq |x_k x_{k+1}|^2$.

Add up both inequalities and apply that $|AB|^2 + |BC|^2 = |AC|^2$.

Note: There is a small issue of when $ABD$ or $BCD$ is empty, which prevents us from applying the induction hypothesis. However, what we simply do is to continue cutting up the right triangles till we get a split of the points.

**Corollary:** Your question

**Proof:**

> Let the square be $ABCD$. Throw in points $A, B, C, D$ if they are not already in the list. Apply the Lemma to triangle $ABC$ and $BCD$, and we are done. You will need to apply a step of the Lemma's proof to remove $A, B, C, D$ if need be.

**Followup:** Can you classify all equality cases? Consider how the Lemma is proven.

Comment: Can you explain why $\angle x_iDx_{i+1}$ is at most $90^{ \circ}$? Also I don't understand  the proof of Lemma "when ABD or BCD is empty" and "You will need to apply a step of the Lemma's proof to remove A,B,C,D if need be"

Comment: @user64494 $x_i, x_{i+1}$ are points within $ABD$, hence $\angle x_i D x_{i+1} \leq \angle ADB = 90^\circ$. For your second statement, if ABD or BCD do not contain any of the $n$ points, then we cannot apply the induction hypothesis directly (since we want to show it is true for $n$ points). For the final proof, note that $A, B, C, D$ need not be in the $n$ points that were given. However, the lemma needs these points, so I'm throwing them in. I'm claiming that we can retroactively remove these points, using the fact that $|x_iD|^2 + |Dx_{i+1} | ^2 \geq |x_i x_{i+1} |^2$.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin: When you split $\triangle ABC$ in $\triangle ABD$ and  $\triangle BDC$, the hypotenuse of $\triangle ABD$ is $AB$, not $AD$. Also the cycle should include only the given points, no more and no less.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, and that is why the lemma uses $AB$ and $BC$ in the RHS. Yes, and that is why I told you that you need to apply a step of the Lemma to remove $A,B,C,D$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)! Just a small observation: the lemma can be replaced with an equivalent but slightly simpler one: $|Ax_1|^2+|x_1x_2|^2+\cdots +|x_{n-1}x_n|^2+|x_nC|^2\le|AC|^2$.

Comment: @Landscape I agree, but this version motivates the induction + creation of $D$.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I didn't notice the squares above the norms. With those in place, it is true that there is a permutation of vertices such that 
$$\|x_1-x_2\|^2 +\|x_2-x_3\|^2+\cdots+\|x_n-x_1\| ^2 \leq 4. \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

The approach is to create a problem instance (i.e. a set of points) that maximizes the shortest (in the sense of inequality $(\spadesuit)$) cycle and the key point is the combination of:

- Pythagorean theorem: $a^2+b^2=c^2$ in any right-angled triangle,
- the hypotenuse of any right triangle makes the diameter of circumcircle.

Consider the following pictures.
[image: tsp_perm]

Any point that lies in the red circle (like $X$) may be skipped thus making the cycle longer (it stays the same if the point lies on the circle, like $X'$). Also, for any point that lies beyond the red line (like $Y$), the intermediate point $B$ maybe skipped for the same reason. In other words, for any problem instance that maximizes the shortest cycle, there may be no points like $X$ or like $Y$ (otherwise the instance could be modified so that shortest cycle could be made longer). This implies that for any instance with shortest cycle of length $L$, there exists an instance of $4$ vertices which shortest cycle is at least of length $L$. This (I will skip cases of $n < 4$ here) implies $(\spadesuit)$.

I hope this helps ;-)

**Edit:**

Some more explanation. For example the corollary from the second picture is this: let $A$ be a set of points in question and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ a sequence that is the shortest cycle (in the sense of inequality $(\spadesuit)$). Then if there is an $x_i$ such that $|\angle x_{i-1}x_ix_{i+1}| > \frac{\pi}{2}$, then for $B = A \setminus \{x_i\}$ the shortest cycle is longer than the shortest cycle in $A$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If we put $$x_1=(0,1),\, x_2=(1,1),\, x_3=(1,0),\,  \,x_4=(0.5,\varepsilon),\, x_5=(0,0),$$ then the sum of the squared distances equals $3.5 +2\varepsilon^2 \le 4$ if $\varepsilon \ge 0, \varepsilon \le 0.5.$

Comment: You are right, didn't noticed the squares...

Comment: @user64494 Fixed now, see the edit.

Comment: @ dtldarek : In particular, I don't understand "that maximizes the shortest path".

Comment: @user64494 The opposite of $(\spadesuit)$ is "the shortest path through all those points in any order is longer than $4$". What I'm trying to do is to show, that for any set of points $A$ there exists set of four points $B$ such that the shortest path through $A$ is shorter than shortest path through $B$. However, it is trivial that the shortest path through $B$ is of length $\leq 4$ and so the shortest path through $A$ is too, hence $(\spadesuit)$.

Comment: I  don't still understand your answer. You wrote "What I'm trying to do is to show, that for any set of points A there exists set of four points B such that the shortest path through A is shorter than shortest path through B". The question does not deal with the shortest path through the given points at all. The sum of the squared Euclidian distances between the consecutive points of a cycle should be estimated from above.

Comment: @user64494 In other words you would like to show that the shortest (in the sense of $\spadesuit$) cycle has length $\leq 4$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of finite sets of points of unit square and $SC : \mathcal{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function that calculates the length of the shortest cycle. What you want to show is that $\forall A \in \mathcal{I}.\ SC(A) \leq 4$. What I'm doing is first $\mathcal{I}_4 = \{I\ :\ |I| \leq 4\}$ then $\forall C \in \mathcal{I}_4.\ SC(C) \leq 4$ and finally $\forall A \in \mathcal{I}.\ \exists B \in \mathcal{I}_4.\ SC(A) \leq SC(B)$. Hence $SC(A) \leq 4$.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in a blog, together with the idea for the solution. [Here it is](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/an-amazing-result/).

Comment: I don't see any formula in the so-called "proof". Could it be a proof?

Comment: @user64494 Why not? There's no need for formulas when plain English is sufficient.

Comment: @ Dan Shved : As far as I know it, that was asked by [A. Vershik](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zbmath/search/?q=Vershik,%20A.) in 1987.