# Generalizing a statement about points in the unit square

Tags: geometry, inequality

What is the three-dimensional version of [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441792/points-in-unit-square):

> Any $n$ points in the unit square can be labeled $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to satisfy the inequality $$\|x_1-x_2\|^2 +\|x_2-x_3\|^2+\cdots+\|x_n-x_1\| ^2 \le 4,$$ where $\|\cdot\| $ is [the Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)?

What is its $N$-dimensional version? How to prove these?

Answer (score 0):

The $N$ dimensional version is the same on the left.  The constant on the right will change.  In 3D, taking $n=8$, each distance is at least $1$, so the right needs to be at least $8$. Since there is no Eulerean path on the cube, it is higher yet.

Comment: I have in mind its proof too.

Comment: These are hard for general $n$.  There are many configurations and it is hard to be sure you have the best.  This is related to packing problems, where even the 2D problem isn't solved. The best known solutions are asymmetric for many $n$.

Comment: @ Ross Milikan : Have you seen the proof of the 2-d version by Calvin Lin? The 3-d version of that proof seems unclear.

Comment: @user64494:  No, I haven't.  Do you have a link?

Comment: @ Ross Millikan: This is the link in the first line of my question. For your convenience I repeat [that link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441792/points-in-unit-square).